# Ads not showing up with Doubleclick banners on Magento

Tags: java, magento, ads, double-click-advertising

Hi I am trying to help out a friend by inserting doubleclick banners on his site which uses Magento. The problem is the following:

I am inserting the below tag in a block:

```
<div id='div-gpt-ad-1482004550726-0' style='height:90px; width:728px;'>
<script>
googletag.cmd.push(function() { googletag.display('div-gpt-ad-1482004550726-0'); });
</script>
</div>
```

and once I save it, the tag changes to this:

```
   <!-- /153419148/EmpireArabia_Ar -->
    <div id="div-gpt-ad-1482002993683-0" style="height: 90px; width: 728px;">
    <script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
    googletag.cmd.push(function() { googletag.display('div-gpt-ad-1482002993683-0'); });
 ]]></script>
    </div>
```

Which is preventing the ads to show up! can anyone help?

Comment: can you show more codes? could be your site js that causing it. best to put a jsfiddle.

Comment: this is the code that I am adding in the block I got it from DFP, I am just saving the block and once I save it, it's changing.. what do you mean put a jsfiddle

Comment: did you tried looking at this? https://support.google.com/dfp_premium/answer/1739296?hl=en

Comment: else you could move the code to a blank page to try and also see the web console for any errors

Answer (score 0):

Even I have a similar problem, after adding doubleclick tag, onsite it is appearing twice.

Out of three ads one ad is showing but other two are not. When I view source, I see the body tag twice.